# rails pulling data from another table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
<% @checkouts.reverse.each do |checkout| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= checkout.radio_num %></td>
    <th colspan="3"></th>
    <td><%= checkout.badge %></td>
    <th colspan="3"></th>
  </tr>
    <% @staffs.each do |staff| %>
        <% if checkout.badge == staff.badge %>
        <tr>
            <td><%= staff.name %></td>
            <th colspan="3"></th>
            <td><%= staff.dept %></td>
        </tr>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>   
  <tr>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_checkout_path(checkout) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', checkout, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

I'm new to ruby on rails, and I'm trying to create a checkout/return application for radios. Is there something I need to do within my views/checkouts to allow access to my Staffs table?

I get the error on line 8

> undefined method `badge' for nil:NilClass

This is the controller code that was asked

```
class StaffsController < ApplicationController

def index
@staffs = Staff.all
end

def show
@staff = Staff.find(params[:id])
end

def new
@staff = Staff.new
end

def create
@staff = Staff.new(staff_params)
if @staff.save
  redirect_to(:action => 'index')
else
  render('new')
end
end

def edit
@staff = Staff.find(params[:id])
end

def update
@staff = Staff.find(params[:id])
if @staff.update_attributes(staff_params)
  redirect_to(:action => 'show', :id => @staff.id)
else
  render('index')
end
end

def delete
@staff = Staff.find(params[:id])
end

def destroy
Staff.find(params[:id]).destroy
redirect_to(:action => 'index')
end

private

def staff_params
params.require(:staff).permit(:badge, :name, :dept)
end

end
```

Thanks!

Comment: `@checkout` is defined ?

Comment: i made a mistake on that part, but <% @staffs.each do |staff| %> is not recognized

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The view in question is the checkout/index view which will reference the CheckoutController's index action/method. This is due to rails convention over configuration. If the `@staffs` instance variable isn't defined on that controller method/action then a nil:NilClass error will be thrown.

Your controller should look something like this.

```
class CheckoutController < ApplicationController
  def index
    # avoid calling ActiveRecord query methods in the view
    # Checkout.all.reverse or
    @checkouts = Checkout.order(created_at: :desc)
    @staffs = Staff.all
  end
end
```

It is also good practice to avoid logic in the views. It feels natural as a beginner to place logic in the view, but as time passes you will see your views become more complex and cognitive overhead increases.

Helper methods are a good place to start encapsulates some of logic in the view.

```
module CheckoutHelper
  def equal_badge?(checkout_badge, staff_badge)
    checkout_badge == staff_badge
  end
end
```

And call it in the view using

```
<% if equal_badge(checkout.badge, staff.badge) %>
```

Another cool trick in rails is rendering partials for collections (what you have stored within the staff and checkout instance variables at the moment).

Create a _staff_list.html.erb which contains

```
  <% if equal_badge(checkout.badge, staff.badge) %>
    <tr>
      <td><% staff.name %>
      <!-- etc, etc -->
  <% end %>
```

And in the checkouts/index view render that partial by

```
<%= render partial: "checkouts/staff_list", collection: @staffs, locals: { checkout: checkout } %>
```

It's more than you asked for, but I hope this helps a bit.

Answer (score 0):

you are using `@checkout` (on line 9) but the local variable you declare (on line 1)  is actually called `checkout`

Likewise, you are using `@staff` but the variable you actually have available to you is `staff`

So for line 9 you should instead have:

```
   <% if checkout.badge == staff.badge %>
```

Be aware that you do not need to use `@variables` inside your template unless they are something that was set up in the controller.

In this case, it looks like you set up the variables: `@staffs` and `@checkouts` in the controller... they appear to be arrays of things. `@staff` and `@checkout were not set up in the controller - they are just local variables, and so are correctly named without the`@`

Comment: Ah ok, thanks for the variable clarification.
But it's still not recognizing the line above that
    <% @staffs.each do |staff| %>
is where I'm encountering an error

Comment: Please add your controller code so we can see where the @staffs variable is being assigned.

Comment: And the view in question is the checkout/show view?